How do I fix my clicker game from reverting the code after pressing the "im feeling lucky" game
So every time I try to click the "im feeling lucky button, it works for a second, then it decides to go back to the original number but adds a click from the autoclicker part of the code. Here is the code (also ignore the cooldown that was just for testing to make sure it works):
gambling.js:
function initClickerGame() {
  // Obtain references to counter, button, and message elements
  const counterEl = document.getElementById('counter');
  const luckyBtn = document.getElementById('luckyBtn');
  const messageEl = document.getElementById('message');
  let isCooldown = false;

  luckyBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (isCooldown) {
      messageEl.textContent = 'Cooldown in effect. Please wait 30 seconds.';
      messageEl.style.display = 'block';
      return;
    }

    const gamble = Math.random();
    let points = parseInt(counterEl.textContent) || 0; // Retrieve current points and convert to integer

    if (points < 100) {
      messageEl.textContent = 'You need at least 100 points to gamble.';
    } else {
      if (gamble < 0.4) {
        const pointsWon = Math.floor(points / 2);
        points += pointsWon;
        counterEl.textContent = points;
        messageEl.textContent = `You won ${pointsWon} points!`;
      } else if (gamble >= 0.4 && gamble < 0.7) {
        const pointsLost = Math.floor(points / 3);
        if (pointsLost >= points) {
          points = 0;
          counterEl.textContent = points;
          messageEl.textContent = 'You lost all your points!';
        } else {
          points -= pointsLost;
          counterEl.textContent = points;
          messageEl.textContent = `You lost ${pointsLost} points!`;
        }
      } else if (gamble >= 0.7 && gamble < 0.9) {
        points *= 2;
        counterEl.textContent = points;
        messageEl.textContent = `Congratulations! Your points have been doubled!`;
      } else {
        points = 0;
        counterEl.textContent = points;
        messageEl.textContent = 'Bad luck! You lost all points!';
      }
    }

    messageEl.style.display = 'block';
    isCooldown = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
      isCooldown = false;
      messageEl.style.display = 'none';
    }, 3); // 30 seconds cooldown
  });
}

window.onload = initClickerGame;


index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clicker Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 id="counter" class="counter">0</h1>
        <br>
        <button class="clicker" id="clickerBtn">Click Me!</button><br><br>
        <button class="clicker" id="upgradeBtn">Buy Upgrader (Cost: 10)</button><br><br>
        <button class="clicker" id="luckyBtn">I'm Feeling Lucky</button><br><br>
        <button class="clicker" id="saveBtn" onclick="saveProgress()">Save Game</button><br><br>
        <button class="clicker" id="loadBtn" onclick="loadProgress()">Load Game</button><br><br>
        <button class="clicker" id="resetBtn" onclick="confirmReset()">Reset Game</button><br>
    </div>

    <div class="message" id="message"></div>

    <script src="anticheat.js"></script>
    <script src="gambling.js"></script>
    <script src="save.js"></script>

    <script>
        const counterEl = document.querySelector('.counter');
        let count = 0;
        let clickValue = 1;
        let upgradeCost = 10;
        let upgradeMultiplier = 2;
        let upgradeLevel = 1;
        let isCooldown = false;

        const clickerBtn = document.getElementById('clickerBtn');
        const upgradeBtn = document.getElementById('upgradeBtn');
        const luckyBtn = document.getElementById('luckyBtn');
        const messageEl = document.getElementById('message');

        clickerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            count += clickValue;
            counterEl.textContent = count;
        });

        upgradeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (count >= upgradeCost) {
                count -= upgradeCost;
                counterEl.textContent = count;
                clickValue *= upgradeMultiplier;
                upgradeLevel++;
                upgradeCost = upgradeCost * upgradeMultiplier;

                upgradeBtn.textContent = `Buy Upgrader (Cost: ${upgradeCost})`;

                if (upgradeLevel === 500) {
                    upgradeBtn.disabled = true;
                    upgradeBtn.textContent = `Upgrader Maxed!`;
                }
            } else {
                showMessage("Insufficient funds!");
            }
        });

        function updateCounter() {
            count += clickValue;
            counterEl.textContent = count;
        }

        function showMessage(text) {
            messageEl.textContent = text;
            messageEl.style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(() => {
                messageEl.style.display = 'none';
            }, 5000);
        }

        function confirmReset() {
            const answer = prompt("WARNING: THIS WILL DELETE YOUR SAVE FILE AND START OVER!! To confirm the reset, what is the result of 100 + 5?");
            if (answer === "105") {
                resetGame();
            } else {
                showMessage("Incorrect answer. Reset not confirmed.");
            }
        }

        function resetGame() {
            count = 0;
            upgradeCost = 10;
            upgradeLevel = 1;
            clickValue = 1;

            counterEl.textContent = count;
            upgradeBtn.textContent = `Buy Upgrader (Cost: ${upgradeCost})`;

            showMessage("Game reset successfully!");
        }

        setInterval(updateCounter, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>



I have tried rewriting the code with a new structure but it broke it more, so I just reverted the code.

The reason it goes back to the original number is because you're updating the counterEl element directly without updating the variable count while the updateCounter uses count to continue updating the value displayed.
You could try to fix by adding count = points; to your function to update the count.
  luckyBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (isCooldown) {
      messageEl.textContent = 'Cooldown in effect. Please wait 30 seconds.';
      messageEl.style.display = 'block';
      return;
    }

    const gamble = Math.random();
    let points = parseInt(counterEl.textContent) || 0; // Retrieve current points and convert to integer

    if (points < 10) {
      messageEl.textContent = 'You need at least 100 points to gamble.';
    } else {
      if (gamble < 0.4) {
        const pointsWon = Math.floor(points / 2);
        points += pointsWon;
        counterEl.textContent = points;
        messageEl.textContent = `You won ${pointsWon} points!`;
      } else if (gamble >= 0.4 && gamble < 0.7) {
        const pointsLost = Math.floor(points / 3);
        if (pointsLost >= points) {
          points = 0;
          counterEl.textContent = points;
          messageEl.textContent = 'You lost all your points!';
        } else {
          points -= pointsLost;
          counterEl.textContent = points;
          messageEl.textContent = `You lost ${pointsLost} points!`;
        }
      } else if (gamble >= 0.7 && gamble < 0.9) {
        points *= 2;
        counterEl.textContent = points;
        messageEl.textContent = `Congratulations! Your points have been doubled!`;
      } else {
        points = 0;
        counterEl.textContent = points;
        messageEl.textContent = 'Bad luck! You lost all points!';
      }

      // Update count with points
      count = points;
    }

    messageEl.style.display = 'block';
    isCooldown = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
      isCooldown = false;
      messageEl.style.display = 'none';
    }, 30000); // 30 seconds cooldown
  });

